# Read only access to Slaves from Server A

Tags: mysql

Here's a little scenario:

Server A which is a Dev server needs READ access to the Mysql databases which are on slaves B and C. No WRITE access is allowed from server A to the slaves.

How do i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

First a clarification. A machine is a client, not a server, not running the mysqld program. B and C are servers, they are running mysqld and they are part of a master-slave topology, they are slaves of another server (just assume is D)

And after that, mysql permissions are the answer. Just define a user in servers B and C and grant only the select permission

On both B and on C

```
GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'name_of_user'@'IP_of_A' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass'
```

Comment: Where the user could be the agent account, I assume.